# Running 2 Nodejs apps through Apache

Tags: node.js, express, apache2

I have 2 apps that I need to run on my Apache server:

- My main landing page (Nodejs app running on port 5500)
- Nodejs express project running on port 8080

My conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5500/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5500/

    ProxyPass /project1 http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /project1 "http://localhost:8080/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I go to example.com/project1, I get the `Cannot get /project1` error, presumably because the Nodejs express app running on 5500 which is being proxied to / doesnt have an `app.get` route for /project1.

How can I make it so that example.com runs one nodejs express app and example.com/project1 runs another nodejs express app?